# scene.viewer.camera.setView() does nothing

Tags: cesiumjs

I am trying to set the initial view for the cesium scene camera. according to [the camera tutorial](http://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/Camera-Tutorial/) it should be as easy as calling `scene.viewer.camera.setView()` — that however does not have any effect, in my case.

```
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', viewerOptions);
const { scene } = viewer;
const startPos = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(4.8951722, 52.3710947, 150000);

// this works
viewer.camera.flyTo({
    destination: startPos,
});

// this doesn't
scene.viewer.camera.setView({
    position: startPos,
    // heading: 0.0,
    // pitch: -Cesium.Math.PI_OVER_TWO,
    // roll: 0.0
});
```

am I missing anything?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it's `destination: startPos`, not `position: startPos`.

Comment: Thanks.  The API changed since that was written.  The tutorial will be updated soon.